# Regex Conditionnals

Tags: regex

I would like to control orphans in InDesign by applying a "No Break" character style based on a GREP expression. Basically, I need to target the last 2 words of a paragraph (That is to say: The last 2 strings of characters separated by a space).

I found a solution for my English publications where **(\H+?\h?){2}$** works like a charm.

The problem is with my French publications where some punctuation requires to have a space before it. I am trying to specify the Matching Pattern based on the last character of the paragraph: If it is a ?, ! or :, I match the last 3 "words" using **(\H+?\h?){3}$**, if not than I match the last 2.

I thought the following expression would work:

```
(?(?=[\?!:]$)((\H+?\h?){3}$)|(\H+?\h?){2}$)
```

but somehow it always default to the "else" statement.

Can someone tell me where I did go wrong?

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58137349/372239) and add sample text and expected result. Another question, what language/tool are you using?

Comment: How about: `(\H+)\h+(\H+)[?!:]?$`

Comment: Thanks for the replies Toto, I have updated my question.

Comment: [Regex updated](https://regex101.com/r/0RmEXy/2), is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

***Maybe you want option (A) below***

See if I understand correctly ...

The requirements are:

1. Capture the last two words
2. Even if in the end it is ?,! or :

(A) Use this to **capture as group**: https://regexr.com/4lr6h

```
(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:[\?!:]|$)
```

[image: capturing group]

(B) Use this to capture **only words**: https://regexr.com/4lr84

```
\w*\s\w*(?=(?:$|[\?!:]))
```

[image: capturing text]

(C) Use this to capture tree last words with marks: https://regexr.com/4lr87

```
\w*\s\w*[\?!:]?$
```

Comment: Be aware that `\w*\s\w*\s\w*[\?!:]?$` matches 2 spaces at the end of line.